# Main will not call array

Tags: java, arrays, random

I made an array to randomly pick either "steak, pizza, or chips" but I upon running my program it errors out well before you even get to the question. It works for about 5 inputs before it gives me an exception.

I assume the problem lies within the

{System.out.println(FoodArray.getRandomWord(args));

but I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with it.

I just need my program to run correctly, and when it gets to the question about giving a random suggestion, it prints out steak, pizza or chips randomly.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int input = 0;
    int sweet = 0;
    int savory = 0;
    int salty = 0;

    Random r = new Random();

    FoodArray a = new FoodArray();

    Scanner myscanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome, lets figure out what you're hungry for."
            + "Press 0 to continue");
    input = myscanner.nextInt();
    if (input > 0) {

    }

    {
        System.out.println("What sounds the best to you right now?\n"
                + "1) Something sweet\n"
                + "2) Savory\n "
                + "3) Salty\n ");
    }
    input = myscanner.nextInt();

    if (input == 1) {
        System.out.println("something sweet. okay. next question");
        sweet++;
    } else if (input == 2) {
        System.out.println("Savory eh? got it. lets move on.");
        salty++;
    } else if (input == 3) {
        System.out.println("Sounds good. Lets proceed");
        savory++;
    }
    System.out.println("Press 0 to continue");

    input = myscanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("pick a number 1-3");

    input = myscanner.nextInt();

    if (input == 1) {

        System.out.println("Very interesting.");
        sweet++;
    } else if (input == 2) {
        System.out.println("Very interesting.");
        salty++;
    } else if (input == 3) {
        System.out.println("Very interesting.");
        savory++;
    }

    System.out.println("Press 0 to continue");
    input = myscanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Next question: "
            + "Would you rather, fly, (1) breath underwater, (2) or be invisible (3)");
    input = myscanner.nextInt();

    if (input == 1) {
        System.out.println("Good choice.");
        sweet++;

    }
    if (input == 2) {
        System.out.println("Would be pretty cool");
        salty++;
    }

    if (input == 3) {
        System.out.println("Trick question, you already are invisible loser."
                + "Lets continue. ");
        savory++;

    }

    System.out.println("Okay. now heres a random suggestion.");
  {System.out.println(FoodArray.getRandomWord(args));
}


    System.out.println("Okay. Lets see your final score."
            + "Press 0 to continue");

    input = myscanner.nextInt();

    if (sweet > salty && sweet > savory) {
        System.out.println("Get something sweet. maybe cake.");
    }

    if (salty > sweet && salty > savory) {
        System.out.println("Get something salty. Maybe potatoe chips");

    }

    if (savory > sweet && savory > salty) {
        System.out.println("Savory! Steak steak steak!");
    }

    if (salty == sweet && salty == savory) {
        System.out.println("Its a tie. Can't help you. sorry.");
    }

    if (sweet == salty && sweet == savory) {
        System.out.println("Its a tie. Can't help you. sorry.");
    }

    if (savory == sweet && savory == salty) {
        System.out.println("Its a tie. Can't help you. sorry.");
    }

}
```

}

```
public class FoodArray {




String[] strArray = { "Pizza", "Steak", "Chips" };


static public String getRandomWord(String[] array) {
Random r = new Random();
int index = r.nextInt(array.length);
return array[index];
}

}
```

Comment: public class FoodArray {
    

 String[] strArray = { "Pizza", "Steak", "Chips" };
    

static String getRandomWord(String[] array) {
Random r = new Random();
int index = r.nextInt(array.length);
return array[index];

Comment: Above is my Array class, the website would not allow me to post the array class along with the entire code for some reason.   I am receiving these exceptions:   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
 at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:388)
 at quiz3.FoodArray.getRandomWord(FoodArray.java:19)
 at quiz3.Quiz3.main(Quiz3.java:94)

Comment: you are passing the java programs runtime time arguments `args` to this method.  Maybe you are meaning to use `strArray` ?

Comment: I've tried that, I get a "cannot find symbol " error. I have no idea why.

Comment: Yes, `strArray` is inside your `FoodArray` class, so it can not be found in `main`, so the question is, do you really need to pass anything to this methods?

Comment: How can I make it be found in main? I thought strArray would be correct.

Comment: You can make it static and public

Comment: I've tried making it static and public, it doesn't work. I don't understand why.

Comment: I can not understand your invisible code.

Comment: My apologies, I was able to add the FoodArray class. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to

::FoodArray::

```
String[] strArray = { "Pizza", "Steak", "Chips" };
```

to

```
public static String[] strArray = { "Pizza", "Steak", "Chips" };
```

::main::

```
FoodArray.getRandomWord(args)
```

to

```
FoodArray.getRandomWord(FoodArray.strArray)
```

**but** this is stupid as `FoodArray` already knows about `strArray` so delete the passing of paramaters to this method and use `strArray` within `FoodArray`